# kubectl copy a folder to all pods available in a namespace

Tags: azure, powershell, kubernetes, kubectl

Im trying to copy folder to all kubernete pods. Below is the snippet of the PS1 I have to automate the process where I'm able to copy to one K8 pod.

```
$MasterPod = $(kubectl -n $namespace get pods --selector=jmeter_mode=master --no-headers=true --output=name).Replace("pod/", "")

Write-Output "Copy over Fragments Folder to master"
kubectl cp $FragFolder $namespace/${MasterPod}:"/TestFiles"
```

I would like to do the same for all my slave pods (which i can list using below)

```
$SlavePodAll = $(kubectl -n jmeter get pods --selector=jmeter_mode=slave --no-headers=true --output=name).Replace("pod/", "")

kubectl cp $FragFolder $namespace/${SlavePodAll}:"/TestFiles"
```

Obviously the last line is not working as it has list of all pods.

Is there any way I can achieve this-where I can replace **$namespace/${SlavePodAll}** with a proper line?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `--output name` you can do an xargs bash script.

```sh
kubectl -n jmeter get pods --selector=jmeter_mode=slave --no-headers=true --output=name
| xargs -n1 -I{ins} kubectl cp $FragFolder $namespace/{ins}:"/TestFiles"
```

- `-n1`  execute the command per line
- `-I{ins}` uses the input from xargs as the variable `{ins}` which you can use inside your command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Im getting below as response on using xargs

##[error]The term 'xargs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Comment: not necessary that i should only --output name.
To serve the purpose you can suggest me any other ways to too.Thankyou